# stop shuffle an array when do submit, but keep shuffling an array when refresh page

Tags: php, arrays

I need to shuffle an array every time I refresh page, but I need the last result when I do submit. in my case, the array keep shuffling when submit.

```
$a = array("test1","test2","test3");
shuffle($a);
$result = $a[0];
```

example `$result = "test2";`

this is my code

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {
   //when do submit $result is shuffling again

   if($_POST["input_text"] == $result) {
       echo "true";
   }else {
       echo "false";
   }
}

<form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name="input_text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

actually, I can pass the result to input type hidden, but I want to prevent using input type hidden method.

Comment: you want to save the state of `$result` upon submission? just use sessions for that, just unset it after making a comparison

Comment: I have tried using session.. if I refreshed the page, the array wouldn't shuffle anymore.. I need to shuffle when refresh the page.. @Ghost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the result alone on initial load. You can start by using sessions:

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();

function shuffle_array() {
    $a = array("test1","test2","test3");
    shuffle($a);
    $result = $a[0];
    $_SESSION['result'] = $result;  
}

if(!empty($_POST["submit"])) { // submitted

   if($_POST["input_text"] == $_SESSION['result']) {
       echo "true";
       // if correct, shuffle again
       shuffle_array();
   } else {
        // try until you get it correct
       echo "false";
   }

} else {
    // not submitted or initial
    shuffle_array();
}

?>
```